# What smartphone model release app do pros use?

Tags: software, legal, model-releases, apps

I am looking for an app that will help me with model releases. I have come across [Easy Release](http://www.applicationgap.com/apps/easyrelease/) which looks like a great product yet what are the pros using when it comes to shooting the photo and  then getting a model release? (I am looking to use this for street photograph.)

Note: I am using iOS yet would prefer answers that cover at least iOS and Android.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came across many choices when searching and I have listed them below. I chose Easy Release due to several reasons one of which is was designed by a professional photographer. Also when researching individual programs I found many, many positive reviews for Easy Release. The rest had mixed reviews if any at all. All listed work with iOS and some have Android versions.

[Release Me](http://releasemeapp.com/)

[iRelease](http://www.ireleaseapp.com/index.php)

[iD Release](http://idrelease.com/) - This is the only Free App

[Easy Release](http://www.applicationgap.com/)

[mRelease](http://www.mreleaseapp.com/)

[Model Release](http://www.themodelreleaseapp.com/)

[Photographers Contract Maker](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/photographers-contract-maker/id356115074?mt=8&ign-mpt=uo%3D4)

[VMRelease](http://www.vmrelease.com/)

---

**Legality and Use**

I was curious about the legality and acceptance of electronic model releases. You can see my [other question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/21329/will-electronic-or-digital-model-releases-or-contracts-hold-up-in-court) for more specific information however I will list a few brief things here for a quick reference.

I asked the makers of Easy Release if there was any legal cases and this was the response I received:

> I'm not aware of any direct case history. Getty Images, Alamy, and iStock have approved us for use by their contributor photographers; Getty did so after a ten month worldwide legal review.

I asked if Shutter Stock would accept any electronic releases and received this reply:

> You may use your own release form, but it must be "materially similar,” containing photographer and model details, as well as a witness signature. You may also use a dual language model release, as long as one part is in English. (They then provide a link to their model releases.)

<strike>I had [read](http://www.istockphoto.com/forum_messages.php?threadid=233232) that iStock did not accept any electronic model releases. The info was dated 2010 and after speaking with iStock this is their response:
 "We do not accept electronic releases as we require human signatures on our releases."</strike>

**Update:** When I originally posted this iStock did not accept any digital releases. That has [changed](http://www.istockphoto.com/article_view.php?ID=1418) and they now accept releases by Easy Release and VMRelease. Though do note, there are a few stipulations on them accepting VMRelease releases, Custom Worded Releases in Easy Release, and releases from China. [Read More](http://www.istockphoto.com/article_view.php?ID=1418)

Hope this information can help someone in the future.

Answer (score 2):

I have seen pros that use Easy Release. The fact that they are using their signature in the application is usually enough. I would have a hard time seeing it not hold up in court. I write software for healthcare and faxes are still common. They are signed in almost the same manner using digitized signatures. These hold up to HIPPA regulations so a model release app should also hold up. The bigger question would be the language of the release itself.

Always consult a lawyer in your state for accurate advice, though. They will know the specifics of your jurisdiction which may not be the same as another person's.

As for apps in general... I've looked at a bunch. All of them are very similar to Easy Release. You could always do a paper release and take a picture of it for a copy...